# Flex: detect end of move function

Tags: apache-flex, animation

I need to create an animation and provide some results of the move function at the END of the animation. However, i am not able to control the output till the move function is completed

I tried the isPlaying- that doesn't seem to detect that the animation is completed... so continues to output resukts before the animation is complete

sample code I tried

private function mvbut():void{

```
    var mv:Move= new Move;
    mv.xFrom=Math.random()*300;
    mv.yFrom=Math.random()*200;
    mv.xBy=200;mv.yBy=300;  
    mv.duration=1000;

    mv.target=button1;  
    mv.play();

    AddinDataGrid(i); //function to output final x,y values
    i++;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an event listener

```
var move:Move = new Move()
                    move.addEventListener(EffectEvent.EFFECT_END, function ...);
```